# Google Material Symbols don't work with lazy loaded components for vue.js app

Tags: vue.js, material-ui, vuejs3, icons

how do I use material symbols on a lazy loaded/dynamically imported component for Vue.js, my current setup does not work, the icons only render in statically loaded views:

**main.js**

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import 'material-symbols/rounded.scss'; // importing material stylings
import store from './store';


const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);
app.use(store);

app.mount('#app');
```

**router/index.js**

```js
...
    routes: [
...
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: () => import('../views/AboutView.vue'),
    }
...
]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

after some trial and error, here is what I found to be the best way to solve it.

in your global styling (or every vue component's styling), include the following :

```scss
    .material-symbols-rounded { // this is for the rounded style, you can change it to what you prefere
        font-variation-settings:
            'FILL' 1,
            'wght' 600,
            'GRAD' 0,
            'opsz' 48;
        font-family: 'Material Symbols rounded';
        font-weight: 600;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 24px;
        /* Preferred icon size */
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 1;
        text-transform: none;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        word-wrap: normal;
        white-space: nowrap;
        direction: ltr;
    }
```

of course these are my preferences you can find what you can do from the [Material Symbols Docs](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/material_symbols), the idea is to include icon styling in your code as if you're self-hosting the materials.